# My galaxy S2 stuck on SAMSUNG logo

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, unbricking

yesterday i was trying to recharge my galaxy S2 - i9100 which has JB 4.1.2, suddenly the phone stuck on the SAMSUNG logo for a long time. i tried to remove the battery but it didn't work. i can get to recovery and download mode but the problem is i don't want to wipe my device since i have more than 2000 photo on it and i don't want to lose them ( + i don't have any backup for them ) :(

so is there any solution to fix this problem without using the hard reset ? ( install the firmware again or make root or something ) Please help me :(((

Answer (score 1):

Some recoveries allow you to navigate your phone with a file browser.
Does your phone have an external SD card?

I have Team Win Recovery Project installed on my phone and it lets me copy stuff around, it even has a terminal to do whatever you please.
So you could copy your photos to SD card using that recovery and then to computer.

Installing TWRP was very easy for me, I remember just putting a .zip in the external card and hitting install from the android recovery selecting from menu. Everything else was automatic.

But be tread carefully here; do a false move and you can potentially brick your phone.

http://teamw.in/project/twrp2

Answer (score -1):

using odin root the phone . .after rooting the phone will enter  into cwm download mode .. u will get extra option specifically the mount usb whilst  the phone is connected to the pc. .the memory will appear on your pc. . and u can backup ur stuff. . .ALTERNATIVELY . . .just flash a working rom. . i did that and i passed the logo stage and got all my stuff back with no changes to the apps and their data just a reset of my phone software as if it was new